# Llamar a una funcion javascript desde otra pagina

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

¿ Como puedo llamar a una funcion javascript de otra página ?

Ejemplo:

Pagina5.html

```
<a href="javascript:irAFuncionDePagina2Html();">Contacto</a>
```

Añado mas explicación, creía que se entendería mejor con el ejemplo anterior.

Tengo en una página un scroll largo con un formulario en una sección en una posición "Y" determinada.

En otras paginas tengo un enlace contacto que cuando es pulsado va al formulario de esta pagina pagina2.html con un link del tipo

```
<a href="pagina2#contacto">Contacto</a>
```

El problema es que por varias funcionalidades que tiene la pagina tengo que ejecutarlo con una función JavaScript donde antes me haga un scroll de la pagina a la posición 0,0 de esta manera,

```
<a href="JavaScript:scrollHaciaContacto()">Contacto</a>
```

Donde la función scrollHaciaContacto esta declarada en la pagina2.html

```
function scrollHaciaContacto() {
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
   location.href = "pagina2#contacto";
}
```

Es decir, antes de ir a la posición "Y" de la pagina tengo que hacer un scroll a la posición 0,0.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer? La pregunta es demasiado vaga en detalles

Comment: Cargando el .js que tengas cargado en la otra página y si lo tienes integrado en el propio .html sería un buen momento para plantearse el sacar el script de ahí.

Comment: normalmente en buenas practicas de programación todas la funciones de js se realizan en un archivo ".js"

Comment: Acabo de añadir mas datos sobre lo que necesito

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro he añadido mas explicaciones, a ver si eres tan amable de ayudarme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En pagina5.html enlaza a la página a la que quieres ir y pasa un parámetro con el ID del elemento al que quieres hacer scroll. El parámetro lo puedes pasar de diferentes maneras, para que sea leído desde la cadena de búsqueda (como el GET) o como un hash, lo único sería que no lo pases tal cual (de lo contrario el navegador directamente te irá a esa sección que parece que es lo que no quieres):

```
<a href="pagina2.html?objetivo=contacto">Contacto</a>

<a href="pagina2.html#objetivo=contacto">Contacto</a>
```

Ahora desde tu script en la pagina2.html, cuando se cargue la página, comprueba si existe ese parámetro o no. Y si existe es cuando llamas a la función que hace el scroll como quieres en lugar a de manera directa.

Por ejemplo, si has pasado el parámetro a través del hash lo puedes leer usando `window.location.hash` (si lo pasas como parámetro de la URL lo puedes leer con `window.location.search`). Y a partir de ahí ejecutas la acción que quieras hacer.

Aquí puedes ver una versión genérica:

```
// cambia la función para que reciba el ID del elemento al que quieres hacer scroll
function scrollHaciaContacto(id) {
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
   location.href = "pagina2.html#" + id;
}

// cuando se cargue la página
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  // obtén el ID del document al que quieres hacer scroll
  const hash = window.location.hash.replace("#objetivo=", "");
  // llama a la función para que vaya al elemento indicado
  scrollHaciaContacto(hash)
});
```

Comment: Ok, alfinal hice algo parecido con variables. Cuando pulso link en pagina5.html guardo en una variable sessionstorage un "true" que he pulsado en pagina2.html. Luego cuando va a cargar pagina2.html  ejecuto un script con body onload="mifuncion();" que mira si la variable de sessionstorage es "true" si es asi entonces ejecuta el window.scroll y por ultimo el location.href

Comment: Esa sería otra alternativa. No te olvides de quitar la variable al llamar a la función o podría llamarse la siguiente vez que se cargue la página en la misma sesión.

Answer (score 1):

¿La función de JS que deseas llamar, esta en una clase de tipo JS o lo tienes dentro de tags  en el otro HTML desde el cual quieres llamarlo?

Si es la primera opción, considero que deberias primero revisar que cumpla con los propios requerimientos de tu función, y posteriormente llamar a esa función con un `return funcion()`, o en el otro caso, si tu script esta dentro del propio HTML, lo más recomendable es que lo pases a una clase JS, tanto por seguridad de tu pagina como por la semantica de la red.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar he añadido una explicación mas larga de lo que necesito.

Comment: ¿Has intentado que la función se cargue con el evento `onload()` u `onclick()`?, eso ejecutaria tu código JS en el momento en que la pagina se cargue o hagan click en el enlace de contacto. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Con onload() en la pagina de inicio o pagina 1 no me sirve ya que necesito que se ejecute solo cuando pulso el onclick   del enlace de la otra pagina. Es decir necesito que cuando pulse el enlace de la paginaX me haga un scrollTo(0,0) de la pagina1 y luego vaya a la sección de la pagina1 con pagina1.html#seccion

Comment: Esto podría servir en principio para ejecutar el script del JS, ahora lo de moverse a la sección eso no lo se hacer`<a href="página1" onclick="return scrollHaciaContacto()">contacto</a>` ¿Has considerado el usar JQuery?

Comment: Ese código que has puesto no funciona ya que primero llamaria a scrollHaciaContacto() de la paginaX  y luego iria a la pagina1. Lo que quiero es que vaya a la pagina1 primero y luego ejecute el scrollHaciaContacto() también de la pagina 1.

Comment: Sobre lo que me comentastes de JQuery prefiero usar JavaScript aunque sea un poco mas largo.

Comment: De casualidad, ¿Has probado escribiendo la extensión de la página en el link?  Ejemplo: `<a href="pagina2.jsp#contacto">contacto</a>`. Se que no es JS pero quizás así te funcione lo que buscas sin necesidad de usar scripts. Quedo atento a tu respuesta.

Comment: Asi me va directo con href="pagina2.html#contacto" y ya sabia que se podía hacer pero necesito que antes me ejecute una funcion script que me hace unos cambios dinámicamente en pagina2.html y(solo existe en pagina2.html) y el nombre de esa funcion me la debe pasar pagina5.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es meter las funciones de las paginas en archivos ".js", ejemplo
funcionespagina2.js, y mandar llamar este archivo con las funciones javascript desde la pagina en que la ocupas que en este caso es la pagina5.html.

Ejemplo de como mandar llamar un archivo ".js" desde html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script src="funcionespagina2.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: Aunque lo hiciera asi no serviría ya que la función JavaScript no debe ejecutarse en la pagina5.html sino en la pagina2.html. Al hacer click tiene que ir a la pagina2.html y luego ejecutar el script